# Formatting to percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying out a few different queries and I don't seem to be able to get the formatting in percentage both of the numbers I am dividing are floating point numbers.

```
SELECT p.name, s.name, CAST(CAST(ROUND(r.result/s.record, 2)*100 as DECIMAL(18, 2)) as VARCHAR(100)) + ' %'  as percentage 
FROM people p, results r, sports s 
WHERE p.ID=r.peopleID AND s.ID = r.sportID;

SELECT p.name, s.name, FORMAT((r.result/s.record), 'Percent') as percentage 
FROM people p, results r, sports s 
WHERE p.ID=r.peopleID AND s.ID = r.sportID;

SELECT p.name, s.name, FORMAT((r.result/s.record), 'P3') as percentage 
FROM people p, results r, sports s 
WHERE p.ID=r.peopleID AND s.ID = r.sportID;

SELECT p.name, s.name, FORMAT(r.result/s.record)*100 as percentage 
FROM people p, results r, sports s 
WHERE p.ID=r.peopleID AND s.ID = r.sportID;
```

I want this format 90.32% but I seem to be getting floating points or whole numbers 1 and 0 
Where 0.5 = 0
and 1.15 = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many databases do integer division.  You can fix this by converting the value to non-integer:

```
r.result * 1.0 / s.record
```

You should also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.